# View of all cards, across all boards, assigned to me?

Tags: trello

To help me plan my work day / week, I'd love to see all cards across all boards that are assigned to me, in one place. A global 'board' for my tasks, I suppose.

I can filter cards within a board to see those assigned to me, which is helpful. But that global view would also be a big help. Does that view exist?

Comment: Great idea! I am pushing for us to start to use it. With one board for each big project, and us working on multiple projects, it can be easy to loose track of something.

Comment: That's our use case as well. This feature would get me out of my text file that lists all of my priorities.

Answer (score 6):

The view you were looking for exists now:

[The New Cards Page](http://blog.trello.com/the-new-cards-page/)

Comment: I think would be good to hide cards that are already in "Done!" list

Comment: Agreed @HernánEche - Some kind of filtering would be good. For my workflow, I found it easier to remove myself from cards which I had done (as a workaround). It's easy to hover over them on the board and hit Space.

Answer (score 5):

That's already down as an idea named [Place to see all cards (on any board) assigned to a member](https://trello.com/card/board/place-to-see-all-cards-on-any-board-assigned-to-a-member/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e95a6f33bf0faa9d656b595) in the [Trello board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).

You can vote for it! (80 other people already have)

Comment: Thanks! Just voted for it. Didn't even know that Trello board existed.

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for this use case (even though I use it to see multiple boards, lists and members accross projects to plan ahead, not just mine). A few months ago I released an open source project on Github for this use case: https://github.com/natterstefan/react-trello-multiboard.

React-Trello-Multiboard is an open source app displaying multiple cards of several Trello boards and lists. The cards and lists can be filtered by people (eg. only you or others as well) and/or "sprints" (or weeks, however you call it).

Visit https://multiboardfortrello.com/ for more details and a live example.